# Using properties instead of fields in class methods of the same unit is a bad practice?

Tags: delphi

I have declared a private field and a public property for a given class.

From other units I can access the field through the public property that provides access to it.

But inside the same unit where this class is declared I have the choice to access the field directly *or* through the property.

What is the suggested best practice: direct read/write to the field or through the property that provides read and write access to it?

Comment: Generally, if you are outside of the class (the one with the field and the property), it makes slightly more sense to use only the property.

Comment: Recent versions of Delphi allow to declare the field as `strict private` which will prohibit the use of the field from outside the class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Contrary to [David's taste](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8282233/757830), I always use the private/protected field, but only within the same class (when private) or within a derivative (when protected). Strangly enough, the reason is readability for me too:

- By now, FCount reads as Count,
- Using the private field makes it clear I am working on internals,
- And in the sporadic situation where I use the property, then it is obvious that I *need* to trigger the setter or getter behind it.

The key point here is being consistent. Choose one, and stick to it. There is no right nor wrong.

**Update due to Jerry's comment:**

My point about being consistent is a general advise for everyone's own benefit. Accustom yourself with one *default* syntax, and your code will be crystal clear (to you I mean) for the rest of your life.

Of course, when you choose using private fields, there will be incidental situations you must use the property instead. But this applies vice versa: if you choose to use the property, then there will be situations you have to use the private field. I am only saying that when you stick to a system, the exceptions will more clearly look like exceptions.

Comment: I disagree with that last line "Choose one and stick to it" - as other comments here mention, it depends on what you intend to do. If your property has a getter/setter method behind it, then you need to be careful how you use it. Suppose you have `property Caption: String read FCaption write SetCaption` and `SetCaption` does a series of this and that to validate the value, but all you need to do is explicitly assign that field without that checking, of course you would need to set `FCaption:= 'My Value'` and NOT `Caption:= 'My Value'`.

Comment: I've chosen this answer because after some investigation I've noticed that is the practice used for most of the VCL/RTL units

Comment: @FabioVitale But don't forget to take a look at general OOP principles, like SOLID, which are always worth knowing when designing your classes.

Answer (score 6):

Well, this is probably a matter largely for personal taste.

Myself I would always opt for the property, even when coding internal to the class that declares the property. For example, Count rather than FCount reads better, in my view.

Another perspective would be that if you have exposed a property to the public, and it is good enough for public consumption, then it should be fine for private consumption.

Yet another take would be that if you opt to use the most publicly available interface wherever possible, then it will be more obvious when you are using something private. So, if you find that you need to write FCount because there is no Count, then you have a gentle reminder that this is a private name that you are using.

So, as I said, no definitive answer, just my own personal opinions and preferences.

Comment: The only problem with a statement like "always opt for the property" is when the property has a setter that has side effects (eg., performing a calculation or setting other properties) that you may not want to happen internally. :)

Comment: @ken Good point. I'm implicitly assuming that the property maps directly onto the field. I think that's hinted at in the question but nowhere is it explicit.

Comment: @David Even if so, classes evolve.

Comment: For me exceptions to the "opt for the property" are constructors, destructor and similar methods such as Assign or CreateCopy. I have seen a couple to many assign methods that go through the setters and getters and cause av's or leaks because not all setters have the same behaviour wrt doing an assigned check and freeing the current instance. In "construction" methods I go for the fields and in the rare circumstance I don't (don't ask it's a long story), I explain why in comments.

Comment: I was just about to answer with the exact same point that Ken mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

If you do not use any getter and setter, it is just a matter of taste. Using the property or the field will generate the exact same code.

If you do use getter and setter, you can expicitely use the private field if you do not want to use the getter/setter code (e.g. in the `constructor`).

If your getter and setter are `virtual`, even if the default implementation is just an assignment, you'd have to check the [SOLID principles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), and ensure that you follow at least Liskov substitution and Open/Close principles.

Comment: I've just finished a blog article about [SOLID principles](http://blog.synopse.info/post/2011/11/27/SOLID-design-principles). Definitively I'm not a very polished coder (I confess I break those principles sometimes, even in my Open Source libraries) - but I'd be interested in reading your comments, and let such principles be better known in the Delphi community. Delphi is sometimes assimilated to a RAD product - and this is a marketing label - but IMHO Delphi is much more than RAD. With Delphi, you can make very serious and clean programming.

Comment: hi. broken link :)

Comment: The blog article has been included to our framework documentation, and completed. [A working link to the article](https://synopse.info/files/html/Synopse%20mORMot%20Framework%20SAD%201.18.html#TITL_47).