# Is it a good idea to make fields protected?

Tags: delphi, oop, delphi-2007

Code example:

```
unit Foo;

  TFoo = class
  protected
    FList: TList; // Lifetime is managed by constructor and destructor
  public
    property List: TList read FList;
    constructor Create;
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

unit Bar;

  TBar = class(TFoo)
    procedure MyMethod;
  end;

procedure TBar.MyMethod;
begin
  // Access of FList goes here
end;
```

The TBar class is able to directly modify the value of FList, but that's not strictly necessary, because it only has to call its methods / use its properties.

Should I make FList private and use the property to access it from TBar instead?

How do you handle cases like that? Are there any performance considerations as well?

Comment: This is somewhat related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281582/using-properties-instead-of-fields-in-class-methods-of-the-same-unit-is-a-bad-pr , but more specific.

Comment: *Countless times* I've hit something that would ease my work if the thing had not been private. I believe many others also did since I've seen developers that completely ignored *private* and used *protected* as the strictest scope. +1

Comment: @Sertac That's most usually an issue when you don't have control over the other code. When you are in full control of all the code then you can use `private` or even `strict private` and when that becomes too restrictive you can relax the restrictions as needed.

Comment: No performance considerations. I personally would tend to use the most restrictive [visibility specifier](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Classes_and_Objects#Visibility_of_Class_Members) available that allows your code to work. This advice is when you have full control over the all code that uses the class. If you are writing a component or a library, then you have to take into account users that are not you. That's a different game and I offer no advice there.

Comment: @David - I think it's important to be able to carefully structure the code before you have the need to access pieces of it on a case by case basis. It's also a possibility that someone not in control of it might have to use it at some time.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan So you would go with `strict protected` in this case? The classes are in different units.

Comment: Does `TBar` need full control over inherited `FList`?

Comment: If subclasses require access, yet class users don't, then use protected. If you study the VCL, you'll see this is the intention.  Consider the Create constructor - it's public, and that's because subclasses may override it and inherit from it, but it's intended access is by class users.

Comment: @user539484 depends on the definition of "full control". In my case the only thing that TBar does is call methods and read from properties of `FList`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I agree that you could start out with the least privilege, and move things up in visibility when needed, it's only because it ends up producing proper object oriented design without having to think too hard about whether the class member is a real business function that should be exposed.

You should encapsulate and hide as much of the complexity as possible within an object so that the external interface is as minimalist as possible. One way to accomplish this is to only add or expose properties as you need them.

If you don't need external access to a particular member of the class, it's probably simply an implementation artifact, and doesn't fit the actual business use of the class. It's complexity should, therefore, be hidden.

In this case, because TBar inherits from TFoo, Protected is a valid visibility level, since it's reserved for inherited classes. Also, because TBar is inherited from TFoo, maybe you're thinking it should have some extra privileges to the inner workings of TFoo because it is, after all, its child class. Why should we relegate TBar to have the same low level of access as other classes?

The answer depends on whether FList is an actual class member of TFoo, as we consider what the TFoo model represents, or whether it's simply an implementation detail. Also, what is the level of access required? Are we simply accessing it, or are we changing the implementation?

I'm guessing that you don't need access to FList, and you're not changing the implementation, in which case, even if the two classes were in the same unit, I would still make FList Private over Protected.

If you were merely accessing the class member from descendant classes within the same unit, I would still keep it private.

However, if FList were something that you need to override in TBar (probably not, since it's not a method), or were designed as something that inherited classes should or would override, whether it was in the same unit or not, then you would want to make it Protected.

You would also need to raise the visibility to Protected if you needed to access FList from descendant classes outside of the same unit.

Comment: Also no matter if you make TFoo's fields private or protected, they are still visible from TBar, if TBar is declared in the same unit. To avoid that, in most recent delphi versions use "strict private".  In Delphi 2007 which doesn't have `Strict Private`, move TBar to its own unit, to prevent "implicit friend status of classes in the same unit" that ObjectPascal/Delphi has built into its OOP design.

Comment: If `FList` was private (and not exposed to the public scope) and `TFoo` and `TBar` were in different files would you use a protected property to access it from `TBar`?

Comment: @Jens, yes. With Protected, inherited classes could access it from a different unit, while still hiding it from other classes. If it were in the same unit, I would most likely keep it private if I were simply accessing it, but if I were changing the implementation, I would make it Public.